# WPS Office not showing in "Select Application" default app window

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, default-programs, wps-office

In Ubuntu 18.10 I am trying to enable WPS Office apps (Writer, Spreadsheets, Presentation) to open Microsoft Office files as default.

After right clicking on the file (e.g. a .docx) > Open With Other Application, the Select Application window appears having LibreOffice Writer as default.

However, after clicking on View All Applications, WPS Office apps are nowhere to be found in the list.

[image: "View All Applications" list]

The same issue exists with right clicking on the file > Properties > Open With tab.

[image: "Open With" list]

How could I make WPS Office apps appear in the list with compatible apps for Microsoft Word/Excel/PowePoint files?

Comment: How did you install WPS Office ?

Comment: @Liso - WPS Office was installed via Flathub (I have added Flatpak repositories in Ubuntu Software Center).